# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null, but the file exists

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I found similar questions here, but found the solutions did not work for me.
I have downloaded an image from the web and saved it into the files directory

```
private boolean saveImageToDisk(ResponseBody body, Context context, String fileName) {
    try {
        File image = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + fileName);

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];
            inputStream = body.byteStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);

            while (true) {
                int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);
                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works ok, but when I try to get the file and convert to `Bitmap`, I always get `null`, although `file.exists()` returns true

```
 private Bitmap getImageFromCache(Context context, String fileName) {
    String fname = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName).getAbsolutePath();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fname);
    return bitmap; // bitmap = null
}
```

I have permissions in my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: decodeFile also returns null if the bitmap cannot be decoded. Try with another file, maybe it is the format that doesn't work...

Comment: Did you try to open downloaded file using ES file explorer for example?

Comment: THe usual causes of this are either invalid file formats and OutOfMemory errors trying to decode it.

Comment: Starting from Android 6.0, you also need to add code so users grant 'dangerous' permissions when the app is launched. See : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html